# How can I tell my AppleScript to ignore renamed files?

Tags: file, automation, applescript, rename

I put together a simple AppleScript that automatically opens new files, that are added to a specific folder. This works great! Problem is, if I rename the new file, then automator runs and re-opens the document. The naming convention is limited by the scanner, but is:

- 2022-12-21-191532

1. Year-Month-Date "-"
2. Random number (timestamp maybe?)
3. ".pdf"

Is there a way to make my script only run on new files and ignore files that are renamed?

The settings are "AppleScript" & "on adding"

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    delay 30
    
    try
        tell application "Finder"
            --get the name of the folder
            set the folder_name to the name of this_folder
            --go to the desktop 
            activate
            open this_folder
            open added_items
            
            reveal the added_items
        end tell
    end try
end adding folder items to
```

I tried googling this, but all I keep finding are examples on how to automate renaming files.

Comment: That is just how folder actions work - try moving the files out of the watched folder before renaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an **AppleScript** solution which you may find useful.

This following **AppleScript** code will display a dialog allowing you to enter a new file name to rename your currently selected file, in Finder, to the new name.  Before it renames the file, it will temporally disable all Folder Actions, then renames the file, then re-enables your Folder Actions.  This way, simply renaming your file wont trigger your Folder Actions to run.

```
tell application "Finder"
    if (count of (get selection)) ≠ 1 then
        tell current application
            activate
            display dialog "Please Make Sure Only One File Is Selected" buttons ¬
                {"OK"} default button "OK" giving up after 4
        end tell
        return
    else
        set nameOfFile to name of item 1 of (get selection)
        tell current application
            activate
            set newName to text returned of ¬
                (display dialog "Rename file " & nameOfFile & ¬
                    " to..." default answer "New File Name" buttons ¬
                    {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2 cancel button 1 with icon 1)
        end tell
        set renameThisFile to item 1 of (selection as alias list)
    end if
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    if folder actions enabled then set folder actions enabled to false
    delay 0.1
    set name of renameThisFile to newName
    delay 0.1
    if not folder actions enabled then set folder actions enabled to true
end tell
```

What you could do is take the code from above, then in **Automator** create a new **Quick Action**, add a **Run AppleScript** command to the workflow and insert the **AppleScript** code.

[image]

After you name and save your new **Automator** **Quick Action**, you can then shoot over to System Preferences/Settings and assign it a keyboard shortcut.

[image]

Now anytime you are in **Finder**, you can rename your currently selected file with your new keyboard shortcut and you will not trigger your **Folder Actions**.

I have a **Folder Action** that automatically adds the tag "Aquarium" to any item added to this one specific folder.  This following animation demonstrates me first renaming "file 1.txt" to "file.txt" in **Finder** (the normal way).  As you can see, simply remaining that file did trigger the folder action which automatically added the tag to the renamed file.  Then, I used my new keyboard shortcut to rename the selected file "file 2.txt" to "xxx" in Finder, without triggering the **Folder Action** to add the tag to the file after renaming it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, once my file opens it disable folder actions for 2 minutes and re-enables them. That is plenty of time for me to rename the file, and it doesn't re-open once it has been renamed.